# How does multiple mutable reference prevention work in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

Why it is allowed to do something like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut w = MyStruct;
    w.fun1();
}

struct MyStruct;

impl MyStruct {
    fn fun1(&mut self) {
        self.fun2();
    }

    fn fun2(&mut self) {
        println!("Hello world 2");
    }
}
```

In the above code `fun1()` gets `mut MyStruct` and calls `fun2()` also with `mut MyStruct`. Is it double mutable reference in one scope?

Comment: Also, `main` calls `w.fun1()` and still has `w` in its scope…

Comment: Yeap, I don't understand why it works. For example this is not allowed: 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58364807/9620900

Comment: Did you read https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/book/references-and-borrowing.html?

Comment: I have read rust-book section about borrowing and references many times. I didn't find answer for my question there.

Comment: Doesn't "*we take a reference, and rather than owning the resource, it borrows ownership. This means that after the call to foo(), we can use our original bindings again.*" answer your question? Or maybe I just didn't understand what exactly your question is?

Comment: Oh, this section I understand in 100%. But I think my example is quite different. When I call `w.fun1()` I am borrowing `w` as mutable, then in `fun1()` I am calling `fun2()` on `self`, so I am borrowing `self` (`w` in fact) as mutable second time. Isn't this an example of multiple mutable reference to the same variable in one scope? Or I misunderstand something. Because scope of main in which `w` is borrowed as mutable didn't end when `fun2()` borrows second time `w` as mutable.

Comment: No, they are not in the same scope. Sure, they might all exist at the same time, but only one of them is non-borrowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is allowed because the borrow checker can conclude there is only one mutable reference being accessed during execution.  While `fun2` is running, no other statement in `fun1` is being executed.  When the next statement in `fun1` (if there was any) starts executing, `fun2` has already dropped its mutable reference.

In the other question linked:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x1 = String::from("hello");
    let r1 = &mut x1;
    let r2 = &mut x1;

    r1.insert(0, 'w');
}
```

We can say `r2` is never used, but borrow checker decided it shouldn't be allowed.  Consider this example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x1 = String::from("hello");
    let r1 = &mut x1;
    r1.insert(0, 'w');

    let r2 = &mut x1;
    r2.insert(0, 'x');
}
```

This compiles and runs correctly.  I suppose borrow checker assumes the lifetime `r1` ends before `r2` is created.  If this makes sense, calling methods that mutate `self` shouldn't be so surprising.

(I don't know why the 1st piece of code does not compile, but I am glad rust team made it that way.  `r2` should not be there anyway.)