# Why can I not mutably borrow a variable in two different map functions?

Tags: loops, rust, reference, iterator

I have an iterator in Rust that loops over a `Vec<u8>` and applies the same function at two different stages. I do this by chaining a couple of map functions together. Here is the relevant code (where example, `example_function_1`, and `example_function_2` are stand-in variables and functions respectively):

NOTE: `example.chunks()` is a custom function! Not the default one on slices!

```rust
let example = vec![0, 1, 2, 3];
let mut hashers = Cycler::new([example_function_1, example_function_2].iter());

let ret: Vec<u8> = example
        //...
        .chunks(hashers.len())
        .map(|buf| hashers.call(buf))
        //...
        .map(|chunk| hashers.call(chunk))
        .collect();
```

Here is the code for Cycler:

```rust
pub struct Cycler<I> {
    orig: I,
    iter: I,
    len: usize,
}

impl<I> Cycler<I>
where
    I: Clone + Iterator,
    I::Item: Fn(Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8>,
{
    pub fn new(iter: I) -> Self {
        Self {
            orig: iter.clone(),
            len: iter.clone().count(),
            iter,
        }
    }

    pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.len
    }

    pub fn reset(&mut self) {
        self.iter = self.orig.clone();
    }

    pub fn call(&mut self, buf: Bytes) -> Bytes {
        // It is safe to unwrap because it should indefinietly continue without stopping
        self.next().unwrap()(buf)
    }
}

impl<I> Iterator for Cycler<I>
where
    I: Clone + Iterator,
    I::Item: Fn(Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8>,
{
    type Item = I::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<I::Item> {
        match self.iter.next() {
            next => next,
            None => {
                self.reset();
                self.iter.next()
            }
        }
    }

    // No size_hint, try_fold, or fold methods
}
```

What confuses me is that the second time I reference `hashers` it says this:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `hashers` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> libpressurize/src/password/password.rs:28:14
   |
21 |         .map(|buf| hashers.call(buf))
   |              ----- ------- first borrow occurs due to use of `hashers` in closure
   |              |
   |              first mutable borrow occurs here
...
28 |         .map(|chunk| hashers.call(chunk))
   |          --- ^^^^^^^ ------- second borrow occurs due to use of `hashers` in closure
   |          |   |
   |          |   second mutable borrow occurs here
   |          first borrow later used by call
```

Shouldn't this work because the mutable reference is not used at the same time?

Please let me know if more info/code is needed to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

```
        .map(|buf| hashers.call(buf))
```

You're probably thinking that in the above line, `hashers` is mutably borrowed to call it. That's true (since `Cycler::call` takes `&mut self`) but it's not what the compiler error is about. In this line, `hashers` is mutably borrowed **to construct the closure `|buf| hashers.call(buf)`**, and that borrow lasts as long as the closure does.

Thus, when you write

```
        .map(|buf| hashers.call(buf))
        //...
        .map(|chunk| hashers.call(chunk))
```

you are constructing two closures which live at the same time (assuming this is `std::iter::Iterator::map`) and mutably borrowing `hashers` for each of them, which is not allowed.

**This error is actually protecting you against a side-effect hazard:** it's not obvious (in a purely local analysis) what **order** the side effects of the two `call()`s will be performed in, because the `map()`s *could* do anything they like with the closures. Given the code you wrote, I assume you're doing this on purpose, but the compiler doesn't know that you know what you're doing.

(We can't even predict what the interleaving will be just because they're iterators. Inside of your `//...` there could be, say a `.filter()` step which leads to `hashers.call(buf)` being called several times between each call to `hashers.call(chunk)`, or something else that produces a different number of outputs than inputs.)

If you know that you want the interleaving of side-effects that is “whenever either `map()` decides to call it”, then you can gain that freedom with a `RefCell` or other interior mutability, as [dianhenglau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63628015/why-can-i-not-mutably-borrow-a-variable-in-two-different-map-functions/63628848#63628848) demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't this work because the mutable reference is not used at the same time?

No. The [rules of references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references) stated that "At any given time, you can have either one mutable reference or any number of immutable references", no matter if it is or isn't used at the same time. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58365030/3328502) for the reason behind the rules.

As for workaround, since you're sure that the mutations do not occur simultaneously, you can use `std::cell::RefCell` as explained in [this chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html). Modify the code into:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

let example = vec![0, 1, 2, 3];
// Remove the "mut", wrap Cycler in RefCell.
let hashers = RefCell::new(Cycler::new([example_function_1, example_function_2].iter()));

let ret: Vec<u8> = example
    //...
    .chunks(hashers.borrow().len())
    // Borrow hashers as immutable inside the closure, then borrow the Cycler as mutable.
    .map(|buf| hashers.borrow_mut().call(buf))
    //...
    .map(|chunk| hashers.borrow_mut().call(chunk))
    .collect();
```