# Why won't the reference to self get dropped

Tags: rust

Consider the following programm. Why isn't the reference to self dropped after the first call to foo and how can I resolve this issue without changing the mutability of the foo function parameters.

```rust
struct MyElement<'a>(&'a u32);
struct MyStruct(u32);

impl MyStruct {
    fn foo<'a>(&'a mut self, vec: &mut Vec<MyElement<'a>>) {
        vec.push(MyElement(&self.0));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut mystruct = MyStruct(42);
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    mystruct.foo(&mut vec);
    mystruct.foo(&mut vec);
}
```

Comment: The `MyElement` kept in the `Vec` holds a reference to `MyStruct`.

Comment: In general you should avoid storing references, as it's painful. It can be solved with some reference counters `Rc`, but better just revise your design, so that you only need to temporarily borrow the data, and not trying to cache references to it

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but the question seems pretty elementary (why it doesn’t work is not hard to work out when you know how the borrow checker works), and the answer to the second part is (probably) ‘it’s impossible’. Either kind of question tends to be poorly received here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your code looks a bit artificial and unnecessarily complicated. When dealing with references you should always strive for the simplest possible solution that achieves your goal, as otherwise things can get messy real quick.

Nonetheless, in your second call to `mystruct.foo(&mut vec);` you are effectively trying to do a second *mutable* borrow of `mystruct`, which simply isn't allowed in Rust (and for good reason). If you simply change `&'a mut self` to `&'a self`, there will be no problem, because Rust allows you to have multiple immutable references to the same value at the same time.

You asked:

> how can I resolve this issue without changing the mutability of the foo function parameters

Well, you can't. As I already mentioned, Rust doesn't allow you to have multiple mutable references at the same time. To learn more, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364807/why-rust-prevents-from-multiple-mutable-references).